# Python selinux module circular import while running audit2allow

Tags: python, python3

Getting that error while running audit2allow and I'm using python 3, below is the error. I don't see this issue with python 2 though:

```
build:~$ python --version
Python 3.9.18


build:~$ audit2allow 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/audit2allow", line 25, in <module>
    import sepolgen.audit as audit
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sepolgen/audit.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import refpolicy
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sepolgen/refpolicy.py", line 21, in <module>
    import selinux
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selinux/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _selinux
ImportError: cannot import name '_selinux' from partially initialized module 'selinux' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selinux/__init__.py)
```

Any ideas what could be missing?

Comment: The line `most likely due to a circular import` in the error message hints towards a problem within the package itself. "circular import" means that two Python packages trying to import each each as they depend on each other.- which obviously won't work. May make sense to open a bug report with the project directly.